# Cascade persisting issues with Doctrine2 and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony2 for my application and I am using two Entity Managers; one is for read and other is for write.

I am creating entity manager object like that:

```php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager('write');
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager('read');
```

Initially it was working fine but now the following error is coming:

> A new entity was found through the relationship '`AppBundle\Entity\ProfileViewer#viewer`' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: `shamsi`. Explicitly persist the new entity or configure cascading persist operations on the relationship.

Here is my ProfileViewer Entity:

```php
/**
 * AppBundle\Entity\ProfileViewer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="profile_viewer")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProfileViewer
{
/**
 * @var bigint $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var bigint $userId
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
 */
private $userId;

/**
 * @var datetime $viewedAt
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="viewed_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $viewedAt;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="user", inversedBy="viewers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="viewer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $viewer;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->viewedAt = new \DateTime();      
}
 /**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return bigint 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set userId
 *
 * @param bigint $userId
 */
public function setUserId($userId)
{
    $this->userId = $userId;
}

/**
 * Get UserId
 *
 * @return bigint 
 */
public function getUserId()
{ 
    return $this->userId;
}

/**
 * Set viewedAt
 *
 * @param datetime $viewedAt
 */
public function setViewedAt($viewedAt)
{
    $this->viewedAt = $viewedAt;
}

/**
 * Get viewedAt
 *
 * @return datetime 
 */
public function getViewedAt()
{
    return $this->viewedAt;
}

/**
 * Set viewer
 *
 * @param AppBundle\Entity\User $viewer
 */
public function setViewer(AppBundle\Entity\User $viewer)
{
    $this->viewer = $viewer;
}

/**
 * Get viewer
 *
 * @return AppBundle\Entity\User
 */
public function getViewer()
{
    return $this->viewer;
}

}
```

This error comes when I have created two entity managers.

Answer (score 7):

By default, **no operations are cascaded** in Doctrine2.

You can add `cascade={"persist"}` to your association:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="user", inversedBy="viewers", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="viewer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
```

You can read [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) to understand cascade operations on associations in doctrine. This is important to underline:

> Cascade operations are **performed in memory**. That means collections and
>   related entities are fetched into memory, even if they are still
>   marked as lazy when the cascade operation is about to be performed.
>   However this approach allows entity lifecycle events to be performed
>   for each of these operations.
>
> However, pulling objects graph into memory on cascade can cause
>   **considerable performance overhead**, especially when cascading
>   collections are large. Makes sure to weigh the **benefits and downsides
>   of each cascade operation** that you define.

Comment: I have made the change but now the following error comes SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'shamsi' for key 'UNIQ_8D93D64992FC23A8' ....

Comment: You need to do the same on the other side of the association. The OneToMany side.